# Why would I use static initialization block in java?

Tags: java, static

Why should I use static initialization block when I can initialize static members through a constructor?

Comment: What if you _never_ have an instance of that class - but would like to use the static functions of it, which uses the values initialized by the static initializer block?

Comment: and every time when c'tor is called, static values will be reset. bad!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you might never have any instances of your class. Or you might want to have the static members iniailized *before* you have any instances of the class.

Secondly, initializing static members from constructors is more work:

- you'll need to make sure that every constructor does this;
- you need to maintain a flag to keep track of whether static members have been initialized;
- you have to think about synchronization to prevent race conditions;
- you may have to consider performance implications of the synchronization, especially if you have many threads creating many instances of your class.

Lastly, it's usually the wrong thing to do *conceptually* (I say "usually" because there are legitimate uses for lazy initialization).

Comment: +1 - though if you were going to implement lazy (or non-lazy deferred) initialization, you probably wouldn't "make it happen" in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A static member is not associated to any instance of the class, while the constructor creates an instance. You may use static members without having a single instance of the class, they will still have to be initialized. In this case a constructor can not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

So why:

```
static Set<String> digits = new HashSet<String>();
static {
    Collections.add(digits, "unu", "du", "tri", "kvar", "kvin");
    digits.add("ses");
    digits.add("sep");
    digits.add("ok");
}
```

if the following is possible:

```
static Set<String> digits = new HashSet<String>() {{
    Collections.add(this, "unu", "du", "tri", "kvar", "kvin");
    add("ses");
    add("sep");
    add("ok");
}};
```

1. It introduces a new anonymous class, a file in the jar; not so optimal.
2. The second form is a geeky play thing.

Comment: why is introducing new anonymous classes not optimal? would it ever lead to classloading bugs? or are you just saying you don't want to bloat your jar.

Comment: @DavidT. I have no dislike for either form, but comparing both: the first has redundant occurrences of `digits` and the second creates an anymous class (tiny overhead) and has a misleading syntax for non-java developers. The real danger would be when using a non-static `{{ ... }}` on a Serializable class: then the `this` of the surrounding class get's serialized too. I have encountered such a `X.this` being null after reloading of the object for instance.

Comment: Actually, i found out one difference -> on Eclipse, if you get a crash inside your Anonymous class, Eclipse doesn't even know which project to point the line of crash to (like, say you have a bunch of threads and runnables as anonymous classes)