# static{} in a class? java

Tags: java, static

Code looks like this:

```
class AX {
      static int[] x = new int[0];
      static {
          x[0] = 10;
      }
}
```

I have never seen the use of `static{}` before. What is this? A method?

Comment: This is a static initialiser block. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246343/why-would-i-use-static-initialization-block-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's code that runs when the class initializes.

When the class is loaded and initialized, all the static blocks and initializers are run. This includes all the lines like this

```
static int[] x = new int[0];
```

that initialize a static field, and all the bits like this

```
static{
      x[0] = 10;
}
```

that can contain more or less arbitrary code for initializing things.

They get run in the order that they appear in the source code.